Pandas turns pd.Int64Dtype back to Float
I have a piece of code that parses some data into series, does some modification, including potentially turning a few values into NaN, and then eventually building these series into a dataframe.
(see simplified code below)
sers = []

for item in items:
    type_name = item.name
    values = {pd.to_datetime(value.date_string): value.doc_count for value in item.values}
    series = pd.Series(values, name=type_name, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
    reindexed_series = series.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)
    exclude_inapplicable_days(reindexed_series, type_name)
    apply_offset(reindexed_series, type_name)
    sers.append(reindexed_series)

df = pd.DataFrame(sers)

in exclude_inapplicable_days and apply_offset I change some values to NaN in these series, which has a different meaning for us than 0, that we used as the fill_value.
It's all fine until it's just the series, they have int data type thanks to specifying it, but df turns it all back into floats, despite all series in sers having NaN compatible int types.
Why is this happening? Is there a way around it without re-iterating on df and changing it all back?
Reproducible example:
import pandas as pd

date_range = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01", end="2023-01-05")

items = [
    {"name": "Type1", "values": [{"date_string": "2023-01-01", "doc_count": 1},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-02", "doc_count": 2},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-03", "doc_count": 3},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-04", "doc_count": 4},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-05", "doc_count": 5}]},
    {"name": "Type2", "values": [{"date_string": "2023-01-01", "doc_count": 6},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-02", "doc_count": 7},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-03", "doc_count": 8},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-04", "doc_count": 9},
                                 {"date_string": "2023-01-05", "doc_count": 10}]}
]

def exclude_inapplicable_days(series, type_name):
    series[series.index[0]] = pd.NA
    print(f"After exclusion in {type_name}: {series.dtype}")

def apply_offset(series, type_name):
    offset = {
        "Type1": 2,
        "Type2": 1
    }[type_name]
    if offset > 0:
        series.iloc[-offset:] = pd.NA
    print(f"After offset in {type_name}: {series.dtype}")

sers = []
for item in items:
    type_name = item['name']
    values = {pd.to_datetime(val['date_string']): val['doc_count'] for val in item['values']}
    series = pd.Series(values, name=type_name, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
    reindexed_series = series.reindex(date_range, fill_value=0)
    exclude_inapplicable_days(reindexed_series, type_name)
    apply_offset(reindexed_series, type_name)
    sers.append(reindexed_series)

df = pd.DataFrame(sers)

print("DataFrame dtypes:")
print(df.dtypes)


Please provide a [mre], that means not only your code by also a reproducible dataset to demonstrate your observation.

Can you clarify what you mean by "NaN compatible int types"? numpy.nan is a floating point representation, so I think it is not possible to mix within a Series of dtype int.

@mozway I have edited it with a reproducible example

@MarcoHannemann I mean pd.Int64Dtype() that I use for dtype for the series. It is an int that supports nan, and if you check the (now added) reproducible example, the types of the series is Int64, making them int series that also contain NaN

If I construct the dataframe from a dict and then transpose it, it works because it basically just copies each series into a column, forcing it to keep the data types:
df = pd.DataFrame({s.name: s for s in sers}).T

That still feels super verbose, and it's more operation than I would like which might end up causing problems depending on the amount of data

dtypes in a DataFrame are defined column-wise.
The DataFrame constructor will keep the dtypes if you use the input Series as columns. Here you're using a list of Series (= records), thus the output is a transposition of the inputs and you will now have 5 columns/Series with new dtypes. Imagine if one of your two Series had been strings, then the output dtypes would have been upcasted to object:
           #  Int64  , string[python]   
pd.DataFrame([sers[0], sers[1].astype('string')]).dtypes

2023-01-01    object
2023-01-02    object
2023-01-03    object
2023-01-04    object
2023-01-05    object
Freq: D, dtype: object

One option would be to concat and transpose:
df = pd.concat(sers, axis=1).T

Another would be to convert_dtypes:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sers).convert_dtypes()

Output:
       2023-01-01  2023-01-02  2023-01-03  2023-01-04  2023-01-05
Type1        <NA>           2           3        <NA>        <NA>
Type2        <NA>           7           8           9        <NA>

